# select query which return number of jobs after specific time

Tags: android, sqlite

How to make query which return total number of jobs after specific time below is my sqllite table i am getting current time using Java now how i will make query which return me total number of jobs after specific time???

```
  private static final String TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS = "jobs";

String CREATE_COMPLETED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS
            + "(" + KEY_COMPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TIMEJOB
            + " TEXT,"   + KEY_PICK + " TEXT," + KEY_DEST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FARE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIMEWEEK + " DateTime" + ")";






            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " ORDER BY 
             "+KEY_TIMEWEEK+" ; 

               String mydate =  

      java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: select count(*) or select query would return a resultset, the count of rows returned cud give you the count

Comment: give me example query plz

Answer (score 0):

ASsuming that the query you have written works:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " ORDER BY 
         "+KEY_TIMEWEEK+" ;
```

In the databaseHandler class where you perform database operations you could use a cursor to get the count like:

```
db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery);
int counter;

if(c != null) {
    counter = c.getCount();
}

c.close();
return counter;
```

therefore: if `counter=0` that means that there are no records fetched, and if `counter>0` that means that there are records.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM jobs
WHERE KEY_TIMEWEEK > myDate
```

Here, `KEY_TIMEWEEK` should be the name of the column and `myDate` should be the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You can format the date like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String myDate = dbDateFormat.format(c.getTime);
```

This will return the current system date in the format yyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 0):

```
int myCount = getData();

Handler handle = new Handler();

handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
           {    
             @Override
             public void run() 
             {      
               "the code to be exec."
             }
           }, delayTimeInMilliseconds);

         }
```

---

```
public void getData(){

db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery);
int counter;

if(c != null) {
    counter = c.getCount();
}

c.close();
return counter;


}
```

just add time in millis in handler delay time you will get the desired output.

Thanks !